# How to add in a loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Just started learning about loops in ruby and I'm trying to figure out how to add a number to itself.. Like 1+1+1+1+1...

I've tried variations of

```
    3.times() do
     self.+(self)
     end
```

But always get undefined method '+'.

I've done this too

```
    number = 1
      3.times() do
      number = number.+(number)
    end
```

Although it works, it isn't what I'm really trying to do since it's giving me 8, and I just wanted it to be 4 by adding 1+1 over and over. Also I want to be able to use any number not necessarily always 1.

Comment: Have you seen `reduce`? `3.times().reduce(:+)` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

Comment: `number += number ` will also work in this case. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: my exercise is to add a number to itself a few times. i am understanding that as, if the number is one, then 1+1+1+1 and so on.. @noMAD i haven't seen reduce yet but i will check out that link. thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perhaps having another variable to hold onto the sum could fix your issue. Right now, your number starts as 1. Then your loop runs 3 times and looks like the following:

```
(number = number.+(number))
Loop 1:
number = 1.+(1)  ==> 2
number = 2.+(2)  ==> 4
number = 4.+(4)  ==> 8
```

Above youre actually multiplying the number by itself X.times 
Instead, store the sum of the numbers in a separate variable like this:

```
sumOfNumbers = 0
numberToAdd = 1
3.times() do
    sumOfNumbers = sumOfNumbers.+(numberToAdd)
end
```

or better yet

```
sumOfNumbers += numberToAdd
```

Comment: this did it! thank you for explaining that. i realized what i had was multiplying but couldn't figure how to just add. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `times` you can do it like:

```
number = 1
3.times do
  number += number
end

puts number
#=> 3
```

`number += number` is just a shortcut for `number = number + number`

Comment: Thanks, was in too big a hurry.  Fixed.